# Angular2 - wait for setup before routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular2 client using RC4 and "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2".  When the app first loads it makes a webApi call (to the same domain) to get some configuration data.  This is important - it contains the URL to the webApi (and other things).

I need to not show the login or any page until this is complete.  I try hiding the content until this is finished like this:

```
<div *ngIf="IsConfigReady">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

But I get routing errors if I hide the router outlet:

> Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'MyComponent'

The user could be going to many components with a URL that directly targets them.  I can't put the ngif on all the individual components.

I seems there should be a way to wait for setup to complete before routing begins. With CanActive I can stop routing, but then it will not continue once the app is ready.

Maybe I need to think about it a different way.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use canActivate guard for this. 
CanActivate has following signature

```
canActivate(
    // Not using but worth knowing about
    next:  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  )
```

you can extract url from `state` like

```
state.url
```

store the url in some service. After you config load is returned them navigate to appropriate URL which can be accessed back form service.